# Python reading csv file using np.recfromcsv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that needs to be read using np.recfromcsv. The problem i'm having is that one of the column is missing its name. You can see the csv file here: https://github.com/btel/visualization-talk/blob/master/Exercises/data/crabs.csv. The first column is missing its header name. When I read the file it with my code below, it gives me error:

```
File "prob1.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "prob1.py", line 7, in main
    data = np.recfromcsv('crabs.csv', delimiter=",", names=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1904, in recfromcsv
    output = genfromtxt(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1686, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
```

I fixed the error by using the argument Names = None, what that does it it gives every column a default name from f0, f1 ... But I only want that when names are not provided for the column.

My code can be seen below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def main ():
    data = np.recfromcsv('crabs.csv', names=None)
    print data.dtype.fields

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you not wrap in a `Try Catch ValueError` and if caught then set `Names=None`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use try catch with this.

Comment: When the file is small, and the problem is so simple, why don't you just copy the file, fix this tiny header error, and move on ?

Comment: I think I have to agree with FrobberOfBits, you are missing a single column at the beginning, I'd just correct this and then read it in, if you did this: `data = np.recfromcsv(r'c:\data\crabs.csv',skip_header=1)` it skips the first row for some reason.

Comment: note that [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) reads this fine like so: `pd.read_csv('crabs.csv')`, the missing col comes in as `Unamed:0`, in fact it looks like an index column: `pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\crabs.csv', index_col=[0])` so this works fine. You can do something similar using numpy: `data = `np.recfromcsv('crabs.csv',usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))` by ignoreing the unnamed column

Answer (score 0):

I added a line of code and three lines of comments to your main function,
please see if this is what you need...

```
def main ():
    data = np.recfromcsv('crabs.csv', names=None)
    # I'm using the column names in your csv file, to which I prepended a dummy name
    # you should be able to reopen/rewind the file and read the header line
    # to get the correct names in similar cases
    data.dtype.names = ('n', 'sp', 'sex', 'index', 'FL', 'RW', 'CL', 'CW', 'BD')
    print data.dtype.fields
```